# How to add custom text before price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

How can I add a custom text using a snippet to my Woocoomerce price in the category view and product page?

```
function sv_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit_price', true );
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' / Stück</span>';    
    }

    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Corrected spelling mistakes, rephrased the question to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter("wc_price","addtext",10,4);
function addtext($return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price){
    if(is_product_category() || is_shop() || is_product()){
        $return =  'like Preis:'.$return;
    }
    return $return;

}
```